# Observable Lookup and Aggregate

Tags: angular, redux, rxjs, observable

I have a data structure where I have studentIds = [123, 124] through redux selector.
I also have student entity object in my redux store which contains object details of 123 and 124.
I would like to subscribe to array of [student-entity-of-123, student-entity-of-124].

I tried the below. But I am having 2 problems
1. after the reduce, no value gets printed
2. I need to reset the reduce after step - 2

```
  this.store
  .select(FilterSelector.getSelectedStudents)
  // Step - 1 Here we get an observable stream which has value of [123, 124]

  .switchMap(studentIds => {
    return from(studentIds);
  })
  // Step - 2 Here student-id 123 and 124 are streamed independently. the purpose is I can lookup student ids independently for the next step

  .mergeMap(studentId => {
    return this.store.select(StudentSelector.getStudentById(studentId));
  })
  // Step - 3 Here the student-id = 123 object and student-id = 124 object are streamed independently

  .pipe(
    reduce((acc, curr: Student) => {
      acc.push(curr);
      return acc;
    }, [])
   // Step - 4 Here the student-id = 123 object and student-id = 124 object are combined together and streamed as 1 single array

  )
  .subscribe(d => console.log(d));
  // I am expecting the array of student objects
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use another strategy to get the two entities together

```
this.store.select(FilterSelector.getSelectedStudents)
.flatMap((ids:Array<number>)=>merge(ids.map(studentId=>this.store.select(StudentSelector.getStudentById(studentId)))))
    .subscribe((data)=>{...})
```

Comment: [ts]
Argument of type '(studentIds: string[]) => UnaryFunction<Observable<{}>, Observable<{} | Store<Student>>>' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: string[], index: number) => ObservableInput<{}>'.
  Type 'UnaryFunction<Observable<{}>, Observable<{} | Store<Student>>>' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<{}>'.
    Type 'UnaryFunction<Observable<{}>, Observable<{} | Store<Student>>>' is not assignable to type 'ArrayLike<{}>'.
      Index signature is missing in type 'UnaryFunction<Observable<{}>, Observable<{} | Store<Student>>>'.

Comment: the merge operator is throwing this problem